# Why changing the @Input variable from within the internal component causes its failure to detect new changes from external component?

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, components, interaction

I'm trying to set the CSS class within 'EditDialogComponent' below (which is a modal view), depending on an input property called 'showMe' that is set from 'AppComponent':

1. HTML Code:

```
    <div [ngClass]="showMe? 'ui active modal': 'ui modal'">
      <i class="close icon"></i>
      <div class="header">
        Edit
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <div (click)="cancel()" class="ui black deny button">
          Cancel
        </div>
        <div class="ui positive right labeled icon button">
          OK
          <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2. TypeScript Code:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'edit-dialog',
  templateUrl: './edit-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-dialog.component.css']
})
export class EditDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  _showMe: boolean

  @Input() subject: string

  @Input() set showMe(value: boolean) {
    this._showMe = value
    window.alert('Trying to show modal')
  }

  get showMe() : boolean {
    return this._showMe
  }

  cancel() {
    this._showMe = false
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Below is the code used to include 'EditDialogComponent' into 'AppComponent':

1. HTML code:

```
        <button (click)='edit()'>Edit</button>

    <edit-dialog [showMe]="show_edit_modal" subject='foobar'></edit-dialog>
```

2. TypeScript code:

```
    edit() {
        window.alert('Trying to show modal')
        this.show_edit_modal = true }
```

The problem is after the `showMe` @Input() gets changed from within `EditDialogComponent` (invoked by the click on the 'Cancel' button of the modal), it fails to detect the change of the data binding (i.e show_edit_modal) that is invoked by `AppComponent.edit()` (that displays "Trying to show modal" whenever I click on the Edit button of AppComponent)), since the alert from `EditDialogComponent.ngOnChanges()` stops showing.

Why changing the @Input variable from within the internal component causes its failure to detect new changes from external component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Input` is just a one way binding. If you want to also change values in the parent component you have to create a two ways data binding. In order to do that you have to create an output with the same name of your input (`showMe` in your case) + Change (eg: `showMeChange: EventEmitter<any>`), and emit in your showMe setter.

In your parent component now you can use this like `ngModel`.

`<edit-dialog [(showMe)]="show_edit_modal" subject='foobar'></edit-dialog>`

I've created a full example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c83djz

Comment: thanks for your solution. But I do not understand why I need two-way data binding although I don't need the parent to read the value from the EditDialogComponent. Or _is emitting the input needed to keep the @Input object id up to date for the parent_?

Comment: Because when re redering the components will use the parent value as the @Input again and if you are not doing two ways data binding, that value will remain the same. Thats why you need to emit the change and update the value in the parent.

Comment: The value needs to be updated within the child. The parent is only a setter.

Answer (score 1):

This is working as intended. `@Input()` doesn't cause changes to be detected.

```
showMe="{{show_edit_modal}}"
```

is what Angulars change detection checks.

Ir better

```
[showMe]="show_edit_modal"
```

to actually pass a boolean value instead of a string

What you can do is to make `showMe` a setter

```
_showMe:boolean;
@Input() set showMe(val: boolean) {
  this._showMe = val;
  window.alert('Trying to show modal')
}

get showMe() : boolean {
  return this._showMe;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with same problem? There is no way to make `ngOnChanges` to be called when a property is updated. You need to move your code to the setter.

Comment: Sorry, I replaced `@Input() showMe` with the code you mentioned above. But after clicking on cancel, the alert "Trying to show modal" stops showing.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there as you have it now. There is no underline between `set` and the property. It should be `set showMe` not `set_showMe`.

Comment: I know. I have just updated the question (sorry for code formatting).

Comment: With `this._showMe = false;` you're circumventing the setter and accessing the backing property directly. It should be `this.showMe = false`

Comment: I changed the instruction, but I really don't know why the alert remains not showing.

Comment: The only possible reason is that `this.showMe = false;` is not executed. Try reproducing it in http://stackblitz.com